# React Native - Move Button on Tap

Tags: button, react-native

I'm new to React Native (experiences iOS developer in Swift) and I can't seem to find anything online for how to move UI elements in response to touch events. (Or maybe I'm just really bad at searching stack overflow lol).

Eventually, I want to have a textbox in the center of the screen, and when the user begins to type (or taps on the box to start typing), the box will slide to the top of the screen. However I can't even find a simple tutorial for this. I know that I can have a const style that defines style/position aspects of the textbox, and I can create a second style and then on button tap I can change the textbox's style and re-render, but it seems overkill to make an entire second style, where only one attribute is changing.

Can someone provide sample React Native code, where there is a text label and a button on the screen, and when the user taps the button, the label moves from above the button to below the button?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html it's all right here, your positions will be based off state values that get translated. Regarding the keyboard, you can create a listener and do the animation yourself or you can use this API if it fits your needs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example of moving an element on touch. I use a `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` and `onPressIn`. When you touch it, it changes the x and y position of it:

https://snack.expo.io/@noitsnack/onpressin-twice

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import IMAGE_EXPO from './assets/expo.symbol.white.png'

const IMAGE_SIZE = 100;

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        score: 0,
        ...getRandXY()
    }
    render() {
        const { score, x, y } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'steelblue' }}>
                <Text style={{fontSize:72, textAlign:'center'}}>{score}</Text>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={this.addScore}>
                    <Image source={IMAGE_EXPO} style={{ width:IMAGE_SIZE, height:IMAGE_SIZE, left:x, top:y, position:'absolute' }} />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
        )
    }

    addScore = e => {
        this.setState(({ score }) => ({ score:score+1, ...getRandXY() }));
    }
}

function getRandXY() {
    return {
        x: getRandInt(0, Dimensions.get('window').width - IMAGE_SIZE),
        y: getRandInt(0, Dimensions.get('window').height - IMAGE_SIZE)
    }
}

function getRandInt(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```

Once you get this movement down you can move to the `Animation` API to get teh sliding effect.